# Jquery custom animation on divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have four divs in a row and whichever one you click on, the other divs will be hidden. The problem is that at the moment, when the other divs are hidden, the remaining div is moved over
to the left automatically.

What I want is to add custom animation so that the remaining div moves slowly to far left of the continer - any ideas???

(all 4 divs)

[image: All Four divs]

Comment: This SOF post gives some good info on doing this: [How can I use jQuery to move a div across the screen][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510055/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-move-a-div-across-the-screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<div>` elements are all floated to the left I assume? So naturally, when the first three elements are removed, the right-most `<div>` will float as far left as it is able to.

What you need to do when you remove the other elements is to replace any to the left of the clicked element with an empty `<div>` that takes up the same space as the removed elements did, then animate its `width` to `0`.

So if the 3rd `<div>` is clicked, replace the first two `<div>`s with one `<div>` that is the same `width` (and `height`) as the other two combined, then animate the `width` of that to `0`.

Comment: I might need the divs to be in a table. Can you do this with the td's?

Comment: I'm not convinced tds would behave in exactly the same way. Divs inside a single td should be ok...