# Create a moveable div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a moving div when a user mouses over the text inside my div which is in a paragraph tag. I just want the div to move a few pixels when this happens. I also don't want the div to scroll inside the browser so I want it to be within the browser space it has. How would I go about creating these bounds? And how can I make my div move around. should I use jquery or JavaScript.

```
<div class="box">
<p>hello everyone</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd love to see you use jQuery *without* JavaScript :p In seriousness, though, this question is way too undefined.

Comment: As Kolink said, your question is too broad. I'd definitely recommend you use jQuery, and check out resources like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/510075/147072) or [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate) or maybe [this other link](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?750710-Move-div-with-Jquery), that come out when googling things like "jquery move div". Good luck

Comment: I disagree with that. The question (although limited and quite small) seems perfectly defined. He wants a div to shift by x number of pixels when a user hovers over it. While you could easily expand this into an 'undefined' question, as a base it is perfectly answerable.

Comment: Thanks for those links I will check them out

Answer (score 3):

That's likely going to be easier using CSS.  Something like this could work (obviously expand as necessary to accommodate your layout):

```
.box {
   margin-left:0px;
}
.box:hover {
   margin-left:5px;
}
```

Comment: You could also add some transitions

Answer (score 0):

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/PKCGL/1/)

```
$('.box p').mouseover(function(){
  $('.box').css('margin-left','+=2');
});
```

To make it un-scrollable make it `fixed` positioned

```
.box{
    position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: Any idea how I could keep the div tag from scrolling in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

As cmallard said:

```
.box {
   margin-left:0px;
}
.box:hover {
   margin-left:5px;
}
```

i can see in comment you ask for explaination / translate, so i can sharp what he said and tell you that :hover is like if statement, if the user hover/putted his mouse on this currect class the css code will show, now the else part is showing nothing. (5px left to hover [if] and 0px left without hover [else]).

hope i helped